# Как изменять текст при выборе select в блоке на карте?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Как изменять текст, который находится в блоке div при выборе select на карте google

вот сам код:

```js
var markers = [{
  latlng: [50.44701118, 30.45066833],
  title: 'Пункт 1',
  link: '#'
}, {
  latlng: [50.4266545, 30.5430044],
  title: 'Пункт 2',
  link: '#'
}, {
  latlng: [50.39687412, 30.5033498],
  title: 'Пункт 3',
  link: '#'
}];

var map = null;

var mSelect = document.querySelector('#markers');
mSelect.innerHTML += markers.map((n, i) => `<option value="${i}">${n.title}</option>`).join('')
mSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var marker = markers[this.value];
  if (marker) {
    map.setCenter({
      lat: marker.latlng[0],
      lng: marker.latlng[1]
    })
    map.setZoom(17)
  }
})

document.querySelector('#use_link').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var marker = markers[mSelect.value];
  if (marker) {
    window.location = marker.link
  } else {
    alert('выберите что-нибудь')
  }
})

var contentString = '<div id="content">Тут всё то про что должно быть рассказано</div>';

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.44787896, 30.71912033),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.roadmap,
    styles: [{
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#f5f5f5"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#616161"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#f5f5f5"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#981254"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "simplified"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#bdbdbd"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#c0c0c0"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#c0c0c0"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#757575"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#eeeeee"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#981254"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "simplified"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#dadada"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#616161"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#981254"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "simplified"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#e5e5e5"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.station",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#eeeeee"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#c9c9c9"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#9e9e9e"
        }]
      }
    ]
  });

  markers.forEach(n => new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(...n.latlng),
    map: map,
    title: n.title
  }));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.block-adres {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin-left: 64%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sel {
  width: 215px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px 9px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a43c69;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #c5c5c5;
  color: #a33c69;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
}

a.zabor_but {
  color: #fff;
  /* цвет текста */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* убирать подчёркивание у ссылок */
  user-select: none;
  /* убирать выделение текста */
  background: rgb(157, 42, 92);
  /* фон кнопки */
  padding: .7em 1.5em;
  /* отступ от текста */
  outline: none;
  /* убирать контур в Mozilla */
  margin: 0px 9px;
}

a.zabor_but:hover {
  background: #e50a7f;
}


/* при наведении курсора мышки */

a.zabor_but:active {
  background: rgb(157, 42, 92);
}


/* при нажатии */
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="map" id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div class="block-adres">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6 adres">
          <div class="bottom_line"></div>
          <br><br>
          <p style="margin: 0px 9px;">Выберите ближайший пункт</p><br>
          <select id="markers" class="sel">
        <option>Выбрать пункт</option>
      </select>
          <br><br>
          <div>Текст, который должен меняться</div>
          <br>
          <a href="#" class="zabor_but" id="use_link">Выбрать</a>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB33HcYgZLrls9Uauth_nJGvDkiBk0lAqA"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить в *'onchange'* listener select-а нужную строчку

```
textElement.innerHTML = marker.content;
```

```js
var markers = [{
  latlng: [50.4266545, 30.5430044],
  title: 'Пункт 1',
  content: 'Адрес и телефон'
}, {
  latlng: [50.44701118, 30.45066833],
  title: 'Пункт 2',
  link: '#'
}, {
  latlng: [50.39687412, 30.5033498],
  title: 'Пункт 3',
  link: '#'
}];

var map = null;
var infoWindow = null;

var mSelect = document.querySelector('#markers');
var textElement = document.querySelector('#selected');

mSelect.innerHTML += markers.map((n, i) => `<option value="${i}">${n.title}</option>`).join('')
mSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var marker = markers[this.value];
  if (marker) {
    map.setCenter({
      lat: marker.latlng[0],
      lng: marker.latlng[1]
    })
    map.setZoom(17);
    textElement.innerHTML = marker.content || 'Some content';
  }
})

document.querySelector('#use_link').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var marker = markers[mSelect.value];
  if (marker) {
    window.location = marker.link
  } else {
    alert('выберите что-нибудь')
  }
})

var contentString = '<div id="content">Тут всё то про что должно быть рассказано</div>';

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.44787896, 30.71912033),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.roadmap,
    styles: [{
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#f5f5f5"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#616161"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#f5f5f5"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#981254"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "simplified"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#bdbdbd"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#c0c0c0"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#c0c0c0"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#757575"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#eeeeee"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#981254"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "simplified"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#dadada"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#616161"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#981254"
          },
          {
            "visibility": "simplified"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "simplified"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#e5e5e5"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.station",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#eeeeee"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#c9c9c9"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#9e9e9e"
        }]
      }
    ]
  });
  
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  markers.forEach(n => {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(...n.latlng),
      map: map,
      title: n.title
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        const html = n.content || 'Some content';
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
      });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.block-adres {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin-left: 64%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sel {
  width: 215px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px 9px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a43c69;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #c5c5c5;
  color: #a33c69;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
}

a.zabor_but {
  color: #fff;
  /* цвет текста */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* убирать подчёркивание у ссылок */
  user-select: none;
  /* убирать выделение текста */
  background: rgb(157, 42, 92);
  /* фон кнопки */
  padding: .7em 1.5em;
  /* отступ от текста */
  outline: none;
  /* убирать контур в Mozilla */
  margin: 0px 9px;
}

a.zabor_but:hover {
  background: #e50a7f;
}


/* при наведении курсора мышки */

a.zabor_but:active {
  background: rgb(157, 42, 92);
}


/* при нажатии */
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="map" id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div class="block-adres">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6 adres">
          <div class="bottom_line"></div>
          <br><br>
          <p style="margin: 0px 9px;">Выберите ближайший пункт</p><br>
          <select id="markers" class="sel">
        <option>Выбрать пункт</option>
      </select>
          <br><br>
          <div id="selected">Текст, который должен меняться</div>
          <br>
          <a href="#" class="zabor_but" id="use_link">Выбрать</a>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB33HcYgZLrls9Uauth_nJGvDkiBk0lAqA"></script>
```

Для того, чтобы показывать infoWindow, вам нужно навесить обработчик клика на объект маркера:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {...}),
```

при создании которого добавляете свой контент.

Comment: А как не трогать title а просто выводить текст или какой то блок?

Comment: А что вам нужно выводить? Не нужно трогать title - не трогайте, просто это самое очевидное, что нужно было там вывести.

Comment: Нужно было вывести content.
Я его и вывел, но теперь пропало информационное окно, которое обычно при нажатии на маркер появляется.

То есть сейчас как и нужно выводится content при выборе пункта с правой стороны.Зато на маркере при нажатии ничего не показывает.

Comment: А откуда берётся этот контент? Задавайте вопросы точнее, иначе вам не помогут.

Comment: Контент подразумевает под собой адрес и телефон
Вот так:
var markers = [{
  latlng: [50.4266545, 30.5430044],
  title: 'Пункт 1',
  content: 'Адрес и телефон'
}, {
  latlng: [50.44701118, 30.45066833],
  title: 'Пункт 2',
  link: '#'
}, {
  latlng: [50.39687412, 30.5033498],
  title: 'Пункт 3',
  link: '#'
}];

textElement.innerHTML = marker.content;

но эта же информация должна отображаться и при нажатии на маркер, как информационное окно
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

Но все вместе оно не срабатывает

Comment: > теперь пропало информационное окно, которое обычно при нажатии на маркер появляется.

- Так оно и не выводилось :) Обновил ответ, добавил infoWindow.